# Algebraic Manipulations with Indices

Tags: symbolic, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I am absolutely new to *Mathematica*, but I've heard it is a pretty powerful tool for symbolic calculations.

My problem (stated generally): I have three dimensional array. I define a symbolic operator on it. It is symbolic since it depends on three unspecified arrays $\mathbf u,\mathbf v, \mathbf w$. I want to avoid doing the algebra and let *Mathematica* find $[\mathbf A^3\mathbf T]_{ijk}$, where $\mathbf{A}^3$ is a composition ($\mathbf{A}$ operating on $\mathbf{T}$ three times). I would really appreciate references.

More concretely, let $\mathbf T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n \times n}$. Define a linear operator on it as follows:
$$
[\mathbf A\mathbf T]_{ijk} = u_{(i+1)jk}(T_{(i+1)jk} +T_{ijk}) - u_{ijk}(T_{ijk} +T_{(i-1)jk}) \\ 
+ v_{i(j+1)k}(T_{i(j+1)k} +T_{ijk}) - v_{ijk}(T_{ijk} +T_{i(j-1)k})
\\
+ w_{ij(k+1)}(T_{ij(k+1)} +T_{ijk}) - w_{ijk}(T_{ijk} +T_{ij(k-1)})
$$

I use a periodic boundary, so every index is really $\bmod n$, but it doesn't really matter in this context.

I want to find $[\mathbf A^2\mathbf T]_{ijk}$ and $[\mathbf A^3\mathbf T]_{ijk}$.

I searched (not too thoroughly, though) in the documentation and cannot find anything to help in this context.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: I expect that many readers will have difficulty understanding your question.  For instance, is `A` the matrix operator that produces the expression on the right of your equation, and is `A^n` meant to be a power of the matrix?

Comment: Looks like $A$ itself is supposed to be a rank-$3$ tensor with periodic indices. Altho… why does the $w$ factor in the fifth term only have two indices instead of $3$?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. you are correct, that was a typo.

Comment: @bbgodfrey precisely. This is just a composition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution. Think of everything as functions. Then define:

```
A = Function[T , Function[{i,j,k}, u[i+1,j,k]*(T[i+1,j,k]+T[i,j,k]) - 
                                   u[i-1,j,k]*(T[i-1,j,k]+T[i,j,k]) +
                                   v[i,j+1,k]*(T[i,j+1,k]+T[i,j,k]) -
                                   v[i,j-1,k]*(T[i,j-1,k]+T[i,j,k]) +
                                   ...
                                   ]]
```

Then the evaluations

```
A[A[T]][i,j,k]
A[A[A[T]]][i,j,k]
```

give $[A^2T]_{ijk}$ and $[A^3T]_{ijk}$.

Neat, huh? Bottom line: think of arrays as functions and use your $\lambda$ calculus.

Comment: `Composition[]` ought to be helpful in this situation.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. neat, thanks!!

Comment: One could now do something like `Operate[Composition @@ ConstantArray[A, n], T[i, j, k]]` for general powers.

Comment: Nice solution, but two typos should be fixed: comma before first `u`, and last `u` replaced by `v`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey fixed.